# Why i can not import data to csv with scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I want to scrape a trade site with scrapy package and I make all settings. When I write

***scrapy runspider exp.py -o exp1.csv***

it scrapes but does not show in csv file.
What can be problem? I corrected response to 200 from 204 and site is not prepare with javascript

Comment: scrapy crawl spidername -o csvname.csv

Comment: if you are still having problems can you add more details? Traceback you are getting? PS: scrapy will store so many records in memory and then dump them to the CSV all at once. so don't expect items to show up in the csv immediately.